# Passing Jquery text argument does not work in my php mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

trying to call my MSQL database using a movie title to get plot info. I tested that the movie title does pass correctly to my function using alert statement, so that worked well. The problem is when I try to pass the title to my php/mysql it shows me the title did pass when I use echo $q1 in my php, but I get blank info from my data base. However if I force set a title   $q1="127 Hours" in my php file , everything works. so it's a bit confusing to me.

```
function getmoviepic_mobile(movietitle){
var Movie = $(movietitle).text();
alert(Movie);
$('#dvdinfo').load('getuser2_mobile.php', {input:Movie});
}
```

PHP File..

```
include("includes/connection.php");

$q1=$_POST['input'];

echo $q1;


//$q1="127 Hours";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
id,title,actors,plot,catagory,release_date,rated FROM ".TBL_DATA." WHERE 
title = '".$q1."' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


echo "<div <p> ".$row['title']." <p> </div>";


echo "<div <p>".$row['plot']." <p> </div>";

 }
```

Comment: `load` uses `$_GET` request, I presume.

Comment: @u_mulder I first thought the same thing at first, but then realized the user stated they can see the value when echoing out the $_POST variable. Also, the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) states that POST is used when data is specified.

Comment: Try changing `$q1=$_POST['input'];` to `$q1=trim($_POST['input']);`. That would rule out a white space issue.

Comment: can you show us the output of `var_dump($_POST);` in the PHP file?

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: You could have issues with case. You might use like instead of = or compare lower case of both values. Also, agree with @tadman, use either PDO or mysqli functions to avoid sql injection and quoting issues.

Comment: awesome possum! commanderZ...it works. you can see how that would drive a man crazy..thanks